# Retrospectively rename branch and reword commits

Tags: git, jira, bitbucket-server

I have this repo, `origin/master`

I had a JIRA ticket, X-123.  I created a branch named X-123, did some commits against it, which have been pushed up to `origin/X-123`. And then a pull request made from origin/X-123 to the master branch, that got merged in.

The work's all complete except now in hindsight, it turns out the work I did should really have been against ticket Y-789.  Ideally I want to:

- reword my commits from "X-123 blah" to "Y-789 blah"
- rename my branch from X-123 to Y-789
- make sure the pull request gets linked to JIRA ticket Y-789 instead of X-123

Right now I'd settle for just the last of those; any ideas?  Since all the work's already been merged into master, it's maybe shutting the door after the horse has bolted.  I'm tempted to revert all the work I did against X-123, then repeat it against Y-789, but it seems as if there should be some easy step here (this can't be that unusual surely?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's probably a better, Jira-specific, way to deal with this, but here's how you could do it all in Git.

Renaming a branch—a local name—is trivial:

```
git branch -m <newname>
```

while you're on it, or:

```
git branch -m <oldname> <newname>
```

Making changes to existing commits, however, is impossible; and renaming the branch does no good.  But despair not! :-)

#### Some important background

First, a small aside:

> I have this repo, `origin/master`

`origin/master` is not a repository.  It's a typical name for your Git's memory: "This is what I saw in another Git, which I'm calling `origin`, the last time I called up that other Git on the Internet-phone and asked it about its branches.  It said it had a `master` that was commit `a234b67...` or whatever, so I wrote down `origin/master` in *my* repository to remember that *their* `master = a234b67...`."

Your Git does this with *every* branch it sees in that other Git: if they have a branch named `X-123`, you get a copy named `origin/X-123`.  That includes when your Git asks their Git to *create* an `X-123`.  As soon as they say "OK", your Git knows that *their* Git now has this `X-123` (and that its hash ID is whatever your Git told them to use to create it!).

Second, let's just note here that a *branch* name, in your repository, like `master` or `X-123` is a shortened form of a full name that Git calls a *reference*.  Any full name that starts with `refs/heads/` is a *branch*, so your `master` is really `refs/heads/master` and your `X-123` is really `refs/heads/X-123`.

These so-called *remote-tracking branches* like `origin/master` and `origin/X-123` are references whose full name starts with `refs/remotes/` and goes on to include the `origin/` part.  Your Git just renames a foreign Git's branch names (`refs/heads/master`) to make your remote-tracking names (`refs/remotes/origin/master`).

(For that matter, tag names are just references in `refs/tags/`.)

Later, your Git strips away the `refs/heads/` or `refs/remotes/` part for display purposes.  That's why you don't normally see these prefixes.  Sometimes, for whatever reason, Git only strips away `refs/` and you see `remotes/origin/master`.  In a few cases, knowing the full name is important.  They probably won't come up here, but it's worth knowing.

#### You can't modify commits, but you can *copy* them

Whether or not you rename your local branch from `X-123` (refs/heads/X-123) to `Y-789` (refs/heads/Y-789), the *name itself* simply maps to some commit hash: `ac0ffee4deadcafe...` or whatever.  Changing the name leaves the same commit hash in the new name.  You must now make *copies* of all the commits except the merge.

The main tool you have for copying commits one at a time is `git cherry-pick`.  Let's say you make a *new* branch `Y-789` that has *no* copies of the old commits yet, nor the merge.  (I'm assuming your development branched off from `master` based on your description, but if not, just use the other name here.)  Let's draw this as a commit graph fragment:

```
...--o--*-----m------M   <-- master, origin/master
         \          /
          A--B--C--D   <-- X-123, origin/X-123
```

A round `o` represents an ordinary commit.  One of them, `*`, is filled in to mark it: that's the *merge base* between what `master` *was* earlier, back when it pointed to commit `m`, and what is still the tip of `X-123` and `origin/X-123`.  Another one, `m`, has a letter to indicate that it is where `master` was before `X-123` was merged in, and the last one, `M`, is marked to show that it's the merge commit, to which `master` and `origin/master` point.  Finally, four of them have labels `A-B-C-D` so that we can refer to them as the originals that we plan to copy.

What we want now is to make the `Y-789` series of commits, which will be copies of the `A-B-C-D` series.  So we make a new label, Y-789, pointing to the merge base:

```
...--o--*   <-- Y-789 (HEAD)
        |\
        | ----m------M   <-- master, origin/master
         \          /
          A--B--C--D   <-- X-123, origin/X-123
```

As indicated by the `(HEAD)`, we want to be *on* this new branch now.

Next, we need to *copy* `A` but, in the copy, change its commit message slightly, so that instead of `X-123 blah` it says `Y-789 blah`.  To do that:

```
git cherry-pick --edit <hash ID of A>
```

This updates our index and work-tree to copy whatever got changed in `A` and set up a commit message template, without actually making the commit yet, then invoke `git commit` in a way that lets us edit the message.  (Without `--edit`, this makes the commit.  We could then `git commit --amend` it to fix its message, but that makes one "throwaway" commit so it's not quite as efficient—though we may not really care; "junk" commits are cheap in Git; read on for ways to automate this).

Then we just repeat for the remaining commits.  This builds up a new chain:

```
...--o--*--A'-B'-C'-D'  <-- Y-789 (HEAD)
        |\
        | ----m------M   <-- master, origin/master
         \          /
          A--B--C--D   <-- X-123, origin/X-123
```

We can now make a new pull request asking to merge `D'` (Y-789, which we push so that there is now an `origin/Y-789`) into `master`.  **For someone who knows how** (see below for details), the merge will be trivial to do, as `master` already has the *same* changes in it, courtesy of merging `D`; but if this merge gets done as a strict "add merge commit", the result will look like this:

```
...--o--*--A'-B'-C'---D'  <-- Y-789, origin/Y-789
        |\             \
        | ----m------M--N   <-- master, origin/master
         \          /
          A--B--C--D   <-- X-123, origin/X-123
```

where `N` is the new merge commit.

You can now safely delete the `X-123` label (and do it in the other repository as well so that `git fetch --prune` strips out your `refs/remotes/origin/X-123`), but all those original commits will remain in the *graph*, and you will have the `A-B-C-D` commits forever.

To get rid of the originals is harder, because merge commit `M` exists.  It *can* be done, but *everyone* who has this merge `M`—that's you, and the other Git at your `origin`, and *any other Git user who has picked up merge commit `M`*—has to strip this commit out of each of their repositories that has it.

If you do this, though, and then merge `D'` into `master`, you get *this* graph:

```
...--o--*--A'-B'-C'-D'  <-- Y-789, origin/Y-789
        |\           \
        | ----m-------N   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          A--B--C--D   <-- X-123, origin/X-123
```

This graph can be re-drawn to be much less messy, and in fact, it will look like the original graph except for using `Y-789`.

If everyone now deletes their *names* `X-123` and `origin/X-123`, Git will eventually *garbage collect* commits `A-B-C-D`.  Until then, no one will *see* them normally either: they will just be zombie commits, lurking in each repository copy in case someone wants to resurrect them.

#### Automating the `git cherry-pick` copying

To automate the fancy copying, you can simply use `git rebase`.  What `git rebase` does is identify some set of commits—in our case, `A-B-C-D`—and *copy* them.  When you run it as `git rebase -i`, it first brings up an editor session on a series of `pick` commands, each representing a single `git cherry-pick`.  You can change each `pick` to `edit`—this is the Big Hammer that lets you run `git commit --amend`—or `reword`, which just lets you edit the commit message, just as we did above.

After doing all the cherry picking, `git rebase` *moves* the branch label.  That is, instead of making a new branch `Y-789` to start, Git makes all the new commits on a temporary (unnamed) branch, then moves the existing current branch name to point to the copies.

In other words, we would just run:

```
git checkout X-123
git rebase -i --onto $(git merge-base X-123 master) master
```

to tell Git to start in `X-123`, find (for copying purposes) commits on `X-123` that are not on `master`, and then copy those commits to come after merge base `*`, while also letting us change `pick` to `reword`.  Once it's all done, Git will move the name `X-123` to point to the final copy:

```
...--o--*--A'-B'-C'-D'  <-- X-123 (HEAD)
        |\
        | ----m------M   <-- master, origin/master
         \          /
          A--B--C--D   <-- origin/X-123
```

Note that `X-123` has moved.  We now want to rename it `Y-789` and then `git push -u origin Y-789` to create `Y-789` on the other Git (and hence `origin/Y-789` in ours, and set that as our new upstream).  We won't have to delete our existing `X-123`, nor our `origin/X-123`, we'll just need to convince the upstream repository to delete *his* `X-123` and then use `git fetch --prune` as usual.

Then we'll make the pull request and let whoever controls merging deal with it all.

#### Merging `D'`

Whether merging `D'` is easy or hard depends on these things:

- Were there any merge conflicts when merging `D` into `master`?
- Would whoever does this merge like to strip out commit `M`?  (Note that this has consequences for everyone "downstream", including you: you must all repeat this stripping-out.  That could be very easy, or it could be hard.)
- Does whoever is doing this know about `git merge -s ours`?
- If stripping out `M` and there were conflicts, does whoever is doing this know how to *simulate* `git merge -s ours`?

If there were no merge conflicts and no hand-tweaking required, everything is really easy.  Just keep or strip `M` as desired (to strip it, we need `git reset --hard` and we need to be sure there are no commits *after* `M` as well, and then there are all those downstream problems, so be very sure this is what you want).  Then merge, and you're done.

If there *were* merge conflicts, but you can `git merge -s ours` without stripping `M`, it's easy: just `git merge -s ours` to say "we already did the merge correctly, so completely ignore all the commits on the `A'-B'-C'-D'` chain when making the merge *result*.

If there were merge conflicts *and* the person doing the merge is stripping away `M`, it's a bit harder.  The general idea is to strip out `M` from `master` but keep the commit and its tree (e.g., make a name pointing to it, or rely on reflogs and just copy-paste the hash, or whatever).  Then run `git merge`, which will see the same merge conflicts; but then remove the merge result and replace it with the tree from the saved commit.  Or, equivalently, one can use the `git commit-tree` plumbing command to do this with less muss-and-fuss, but that's getting pretty deep into Git arcana.

Note that all this assumes you make no changes to the *tree*, i.e., that `git diff` of the original `D` commit and the new `D'` commit would be empty: only the messages (and hash IDs) have changed, not the source trees associated with the commits.